# Single SQL Server Result Set from Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Please advise on how to merge two results in to one using SQL Server 2005.

I have the situation where an `Account` can have up to two `Settlement Instructions` and this has been modeled like so:

The slim-ed down schema:

```
Account
---------------------
Id
AccountName
PrimarySettlementId (nullable)
AlternateSettlementId (nullable)


SettlementInstruction
----------------------
Id
Name
```

The output I want is a `single result set` with a select statement something along the lines of this which will allow me to construct some java objects in my Spring row mapper:

```
select
  Account.Id as accountId, 
  Account.AccountName as accountName, 

  s1.Id as primarySettlementId, 
  s1.Name as primarySettlementName, 

  s2.Id as alternateSettlementId, 
  s2.Name as alternateSettlementName
```

I've tried various things but cannot find a way to get the result set merged in to one where the primary and alternate FK's are not null.

Finally I have searched the forum, but nothing quite seems to fit with what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an *outer join*.

```
select
  Account.Id as accountId, 
  Account.AccountName as accountName, 

  s1.Id as primarySettlementId, 
  s1.Name as primarySettlementName, 

  s2.Id as alternateSettlementId, 
  s2.Name as alternateSettlementName
from Account
     left join SettlementInstruction s1 ON s1.Id = Account.PrimarySettlementId
     left join SettlementInstruction s2 ON s2.Id = Account.SecondarySettlementId
where /* ... */
```

Comment: Thanks worked exactly as I wanted. Too many years using Hibernate destroys your SQL skills.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT
  a.Id as accountId, 
  a.AccountName as accountName, 
  'Primary' as Settlementtype
  s1.Name as primarySettlementName, 
FROM 
   Account a
INNER JOIN
   SettlementInstruction s1 ON a.PrimarySettlementId = s1.Id
UNION
SELECT
  a.Id as accountId, 
  a.AccountName as accountName, 
  'Alternate' as Settlementtype
  s2.Name as 'AlternateName', 
FROM 
   Account a
INNER JOIN
   SettlementInstruction s2 ON a.AlternateSettlementId = s2.Id
```

Does that work for you?

This gives you a list of all the account/settlement instructions for those cases where Accounts have a PrimarySettlementId, and then a second list of account/settlement where the alternate is not null. Those where both are NULL will be omitted. Some `Account` instances might be duplicated (if both ID fields are valid and not null).

Or if not: what exactly is it you're looking for??

Comment: Thanks, worked as your explained but not quite what I was looking for (+1 for helping).